# Is it possible to compile two different executable with two different gcc version using one make command in C++?

Tags: c++, makefile

Example:

Target 1: abc

```
make abc GCC_VERSION=4.3.3
```

Target 2: def

```
make def GCC_VERSION=4.5.0
```

I want to compile this in single command. Is it possible?

Something like:

Target 3: final (which contain both def and abc target)

```
make final GCC_VERSION=4.3.3 GCC_VERSION=4.5.0
```

Is it right or is there any way to compile it?

Comment: If you write the Makefile you can do what you want but with different vars (i.e. GCC_VERSION_1, GCC_VERSION_2)

Comment: Note that sometimes a version of gcc will introduce ABI changes - such as alignment or which types of arguments are passed in (which) registers, so although it is possible to mix versions sometimes, it's not universally possible to mix ANY version with ANY OTHER version. (Different CPU architectures have different versions that "break forward/backward compatibility".

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I think GCC tries very hard to support this use case, at least within major version. There was a big library ABI break at 5.1, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a rule which need two dependancies that compile your binaries :

```
all: abc def

abc:
    gcc-4.5 my_file.c

def:
    gcc-4.3 my_file2.c
```

`$> make` will compile `all` by default, and so your 2 binaires with different gcc version will be generated.

Comment: But beware that if you have `common.c` which is needed by both programs, you have to compile it with both compilers.